# Как отслеживать сайт, на котором находится человек, при помощи программы на java?

Tags: java

Программа работает в фоновом режиме. Пример: человек серфит в интернете, а программа должна знать, какие сайты он посетил

Ps программа не вирус, а просто помощник в создании ворклогов

Comment: Никак. Чтобы это провернуть, нужно весь трафик пропустить через вашу программу, а это выходит далеко за пределы "работает в фоновом режиме" и придется делать то ли прокси сервер то ли еще как-то копаться в самой системе

Comment: Просто знаю одна прога так умеет. И как мне показалось, там не использкются нейронные сети и скриншоты

Comment: Без перехвата трафика никак. Ваша, одна, программа перехватывает трафик.

Comment: Используйте библиотеку pcap. С её помощью - как два байта переслать.

Answer (score 0):

Поставте TShark, он бесплатный (найти просто, ссылку не даю чтобы не выглядело как спам).

Там настройкой фильтров, адересов куда/откуда, портов, итд. добиваетесь отслеживания желаемого трафика. Возможность запуска в фоне и писать логи есть. Читать перехваченные пакеты и настраивать фильтры удобнее с Wireshark.

Answer (score 0):

Есть библиотека [Pcap4J](https://github.com/kaitoy/pcap4j) для захвата, создания и отправки пакетов. Это обертка для библиотеки libpcap через JNA и предоставляет Java API для нее. Все инструкции по ссылке имеюся.

Как пример посмотрите этот каласс для захвата пакетов:

```
package org.pcap4j.sample;

import com.sun.jna.Platform;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.pcap4j.core.BpfProgram.BpfCompileMode;
import org.pcap4j.core.NotOpenException;
import org.pcap4j.core.PacketListener;
import org.pcap4j.core.PcapHandle;
import org.pcap4j.core.PcapNativeException;
import org.pcap4j.core.PcapNetworkInterface;
import org.pcap4j.core.PcapNetworkInterface.PromiscuousMode;
import org.pcap4j.core.PcapStat;
import org.pcap4j.packet.Packet;
import org.pcap4j.util.NifSelector;

@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
public class Loop {

  private static final String COUNT_KEY = Loop.class.getName() + ".count";
  private static final int COUNT = Integer.getInteger(COUNT_KEY, 5);

  private static final String READ_TIMEOUT_KEY = Loop.class.getName() + ".readTimeout";
  private static final int READ_TIMEOUT = Integer.getInteger(READ_TIMEOUT_KEY, 10); // [ms]

  private static final String SNAPLEN_KEY = Loop.class.getName() + ".snaplen";
  private static final int SNAPLEN = Integer.getInteger(SNAPLEN_KEY, 65536); // [bytes]

  private Loop() {}

  public static void main(String[] args) throws PcapNativeException, NotOpenException {
    String filter = args.length != 0 ? args[0] : "";

    System.out.println(COUNT_KEY + ": " + COUNT);
    System.out.println(READ_TIMEOUT_KEY + ": " + READ_TIMEOUT);
    System.out.println(SNAPLEN_KEY + ": " + SNAPLEN);
    System.out.println("\n");

    PcapNetworkInterface nif;
    try {
      nif = new NifSelector().selectNetworkInterface();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return;
    }

    if (nif == null) {
      return;
    }

    System.out.println(nif.getName() + "(" + nif.getDescription() + ")");

    final PcapHandle handle = nif.openLive(SNAPLEN, PromiscuousMode.PROMISCUOUS, READ_TIMEOUT);

    if (filter.length() != 0) {
      handle.setFilter(filter, BpfCompileMode.OPTIMIZE);
    }

    PacketListener listener =
        new PacketListener() {
          @Override
          public void gotPacket(Packet packet) {
            System.out.println(handle.getTimestamp());
            System.out.println(packet);
          }
        };

    try {
      handle.loop(COUNT, listener);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    PcapStat ps = handle.getStats();
    System.out.println("ps_recv: " + ps.getNumPacketsReceived());
    System.out.println("ps_drop: " + ps.getNumPacketsDropped());
    System.out.println("ps_ifdrop: " + ps.getNumPacketsDroppedByIf());
    if (Platform.isWindows()) {
      System.out.println("bs_capt: " + ps.getNumPacketsCaptured());
    }

    handle.close();
  }
}
```